# Why OpenGL ES texture mapping is very slow?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an Android application that displays VGA (640x480) frames using OpenGL ES.  The application reads each frame from a movie file and updates the texture accordingly.

My problem is that, it is taking almost 30 ms. to draw each frame using OpenGL.   Similar test using the Canvas/drawBitmap was around 6 ms on the same device.

I'm following the same OpenGL calls that VLC Media Player is using, so I'm assuming that those are optimized for this purpose.

I just wanted to hear your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Do you have any idea of the breakdown in time between the video frame->texture versus the rendering of the texture to the polygon?  I suspect a large part of the cost is the video decompression.  If you just draw the same frame over and over again, does it change the time spent?

Answer (score 0):

Which are the calls you are using ? 
make sure that u create texture only once (glTexImage2D) and next time just update it with new buffer.You can also disable other gl things like depthbuffer,stencil,accumulation,lighting, etc...
If none of these helps , check you opengl implementation. make sure that that uses hardware(gpu)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the bitmap are loaded with RBG_565?Try this :

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.length,opt);
```

Let me know!